# Performance improvement of LINQ in MVC controller

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, performance, linq, azure-sql-database

I notice a huge performance difference between a executing of a LINQ query inside a MVC controller compared to the same query executed in a query window of Visual studio 2012.

**The same query takes 26 seconds in the MVC controller against 3 seconds from a 
VS 2012 query window!**

I used miniprofiler to get the resulting SQL command from the LINQ query. This command I executed from VS 2012 so the query is exactly the same. How can the difference in execution time be explained and how can I improve this?

This is the miniprofiler output of the executed query:

```
http://localhost:49858/TrackingEntry/TrackingEntries_Read
T+28.9 ms
Reader 
25558.2 ms

ExecuteStoreCommands Execute GetResults System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator GetEnumerator System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator

DECLARE @p__linq__0 DateTime2 = '2014-01-03T00:00:00',
        @p__linq__1 DateTime2 = '2014-01-20T23:59:59',
        @p__linq__2 int = 8;

SELECT 
[Extent1].[TrackingEntryId] AS [TrackingEntryId], 
[Extent1].[DeviceType] AS [DeviceType], 
[Extent1].[MobileIdNr] AS [MobileIdNr], 
[Extent1].[Speed] AS [Speed], 
[Extent1].[Direction] AS [Direction], 
[Extent1].[Latitude] AS [Latitude], 
[Extent1].[Longitude] AS [Longitude], 
[Extent1].[LocationName] AS [LocationName], 
[Extent1].[Zipcode] AS [Zipcode], 
[Extent1].[Street] AS [Street], 
[Extent1].[City] AS [City], 
[Extent1].[CountryId] AS [CountryId], 
[Extent1].[Odometer] AS [Odometer], 
[Extent1].[IgnitionIsOn] AS [IgnitionIsOn], 
[Extent1].[MessageType] AS [MessageType], 
[Extent1].[SatelliteCount] AS [SatelliteCount], 
[Extent1].[IsBusiness] AS [IsBusiness], 
[Extent1].[Timestamp] AS [Timestamp], 
[Extent1].[TimestampUTC] AS [TimestampUTC], 
[Extent1].[ActivityTypeId] AS [ActivityTypeId], 
[Extent1].[EmployeeId] AS [EmployeeId], 
[Extent1].[TrailerId] AS [TrailerId], 
[Extent1].[CompanyId] AS [CompanyId], 
[Extent1].[StatusCode1Id] AS [StatusCode1Id], 
[Extent1].[StatusCode2Id] AS [StatusCode2Id], 
[Extent1].[StatusCode3Id] AS [StatusCode3Id], 
[Extent1].[StatusCode4Id] AS [StatusCode4Id], 
[Extent1].[StatusCode5Id] AS [StatusCode5Id], 
[Extent1].[PoiId] AS [PoiId], 
[Extent1].[MessageFormat] AS [MessageFormat], 
[Extent1].[MessageActivityTypeId] AS [MessageActivityTypeId], 
[Extent1].[TrackingMessageId] AS [TrackingMessageId], 
[Extent1].[TrackedObjectId] AS [TrackedObjectId], 
[Extent3].[ActivityTypeId] AS [ActivityTypeId1], 
[Extent3].[ActivityTypeName] AS [ActivityTypeName], 
[Extent3].[Icon] AS [Icon], 
[Extent3].[IsLocked] AS [IsLocked], 
[Extent3].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], 
[Extent4].[FullName] AS [FullName], 
[Extent5].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent2].[Identification] AS [Identification], 
[Extent2].[Licenseplate] AS [Licenseplate], 
[Extent2].[TrackedObjectId] AS [TrackedObjectId1]
FROM     [dbo].[TrackingEntries] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TrackedObjects] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent1].[MobileIdNr] = [Extent2].[DeviceId]) OR (([Extent1].[MobileIdNr] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[DeviceId] IS NULL))
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ActivityTypes] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[ActivityTypeId] = [Extent3].[ActivityTypeId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Employees] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[EmployeeId] = [Extent4].[EmployeeId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Trailers] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent1].[TrailerId] = [Extent5].[TrailerId]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Timestamp] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[Timestamp] <= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[EmployeeId] = @p__linq__2)
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code in a Release build of your code, not just Debug? I recently had a query (using NHibernate) that took nearly a minute to run in Debug mode, but took less than 1 second in Release mode!

Comment: In this case it doesn't make a noticable different if it is running in a Release or Debug build.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to execute your query and look at generated execution paln. It can help you to understand problem. Usualy, LINQ2SQL generate query and executes it using `sp_executesql`. And it may be longer then executing "clear" query (withount `sp_executesql`). I had this problems because of missing  indexes.

[image: Execution plan]

Comment: I don't understand your suggestion. I can get the execution plan when running the command from a query window. In that case the execution takes 3 seconds which is acceptable in this case. I assume that the execution plan is the same when the command is executed from within the controller.

Comment: @Rene, I think, your sql query executes with SP `sp_executesql`. It may cause perfomance problems (missing indexes). So, I advice you to check execution plan